# javamail-remove attachment for a banner image

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

[image]

I want to remove the highlighted attachment notification in the mail.
I am using the following code to add this in mail throught Javamail:

```
htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String filename = "location of image";
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
htmlPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
htmlPart.setFileName(filename);
htmlPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "image_id");
multipart1.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
message.setContent(multipart1);
Transport.send(message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
htmlPart.[setDisposition(Part.INLINE)][1];
```

That gives advice to the mail reader about how to display the message content, but it's up to the mail reader to decide how it's actually going to display it.

You might have better luck achieving what you want by sending [multipart/related content with an html part](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpr) that references the image.  Or, put the banner image on the web somewhere and just use an html body that references the banner using a URL.

Comment: Hey thanks Bill. That totally worked for me.
And indeed the other solution mentioned by you is also correct, but for me, its a confidential images reflecting something for my company. So I cant post it on web!